# Removing substrings in Java

Tags: java, xml, string, xml-parsing

I am trying to remove a searched string from an original string(which is an xml file). For this I used the replaceAll function. However I get empty newlines because I used "" for the string to replace. Is there another way to remove a string?

```
        start =str.indexOf("<opts>");
        end =str.indexOf("</opts>");
        String removeStr = str.substring(start -6, end + 7);
        str = str.replaceAll(removeStr, "");
```

Tried:

```
    System.out.println("InitialString :="+str);
    int start = str.indexOf("<opts>");
    int end = str.lastIndexOf("</opts>"); //if \n is added, indent of tag<nos> changes
    str = str.substring(0, start ) + str.substring(end + 7, str.length());
    System.out.println("FinalString :="+str);
```

Initial Input String :=

```
<data>
    <param>2</param>
    <unit>1</unit>
    <opts>
        <name>abc</name>
        <venue>arena0</venue>
    </opts>
    <opts>
        <name>xyz</name>
        <venue>arena1</venue>
    </opts>
    <nos>100</nos>
</data>
```

Final Output String :=

```
<data>
    <param>2</param>
    <unit>1</unit>

    <nos>100</nos>
</data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this;

```
int start = str.indexOf("<opts>");
int end = str.indexOf("</opts>\n");
str = str.substring(0, start - 6) + str.substring(end + 8, str.length());
```

Comment: Hi Lynks thanks for the suggestion. The only problem with this is if I have a tag below last </opts> which gets indented like a child of <unit> when I try your code :(

Comment: Try replacing the `\n` with `\r\n` and the `+ 8` to a `+ 9`

Comment: Adding a \n shouldn't actually make any difference here. I would just keep incrementing the `+ 8` until it scoops up everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

You are not removing the new line feed after `</opts>`. When you perform an `end + 7` you are limiting it up to the end of `</opts>` but there could be a `\n` or / and `\r` after it.

If you don't want to work with it as a XML content (parsing it as a DOM `Document` and removing each child that should be removed with `removeChild` and store it with a process that will indent your XML again) you could make a post-processing and clear the empty lines after string replace.

---

In order to do it with the XML Document approach you could try:

```
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer        transformer  = transFactory.newTransformer();

// set some options on the transformer
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

// get a transformer and supporting classes
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
DOMSource    source = new DOMSource(xmlDoc);

// transform the xml document into a string
transformer.transform(source, result);

System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

sample from: http://techxplorer.com/2010/05/20/indenting-xml-output-in-java/

Comment: @Francicco: thanks a lot. I tried what you set. I managed to remove the child nodes but then when I did a dom.normalize(), the empty lines still remains. How do I remove them?

Comment: @user907810 did you got it with the last added snippet?

Comment: I added this snippet, however after a removeChild, I am not able to get rid of the blank lines even with the setproperty :(